# Mongo: Roles do not restrict anything

Tags: mongodb

This is how I am starting my mongo and logging in:

```
mongod --auth

mongosh --username 'kaito' --password 'kaito' --authenticationDatabase kaito --host 10.0.0.111
```

And this is a user I created:

```
[
  {
    _id: 'kaito.kaito',
    userId: UUID('f104a209-fe36-4b19-99c0-515a45938e30'),
    user: 'kaito',
    db: 'kaito',
    roles: [ { role: 'read', db: 'kaito' } ],
    mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
  }
]
```

I would expect this user to be able to read only from kaito db, but in practice he can do anything in any db. What am I missing?

`db.adminCommand({getCmdLineOpts: 1})` returns:

```
{ argv: [ '/usr/bin/mongod', '--config', '/etc/mongod.conf'
    ], parsed: { config: '/etc/mongod.conf', net: { bindIp: '0.0.0.0', port: 27017
        }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: '/usr/share/zoneinfo'
        }, storage: { dbPath: '/var/lib/mongodb', journal: { enabled: true
            }
        }, systemLog: { destination: 'file', logAppend: true, path: '/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log'
        }
    }, ok: 1
}
```

Comment: Could you confirm auth is enabled with https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/ . If `db.adminCommand({getCmdLineOpts: 1})` from mongosh session confirms auth is enabled, kindly post exact version of the DB to reproduce.

Comment: well I confirmed it with failed login attempt after typing wrong password and that command says: {
  argv: [ '/usr/bin/mongod', '--config', '/etc/mongod.conf' ],
  parsed: {
    config: '/etc/mongod.conf',
    net: { bindIp: '0.0.0.0', port: 27017 },
    processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: '/usr/share/zoneinfo' },
    storage: { dbPath: '/var/lib/mongodb', journal: { enabled: true } },
    systemLog: {
      destination: 'file',
      logAppend: true,
      path: '/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log'
    }
  },
  ok: 1
}, not sure what it means

Comment: It means you connect to the wrong database. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongodb you started as `mongod --auth` and mongodb you connect to as `mongosh --username 'kaito' --password 'kaito' --authenticationDatabase kaito --host 10.0.0.111` are 2 different instances.

The later doesn't have RBAC enabled.

You need to restart mongodb on host 10.0.0.111 with `--auth` option or edit `/etc/mongod.conf` on that host to set `security.authorization` as `enabled`, and restart mongod to apply changes.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-security.authorization

Comment: ok, I might got it wrong, my tutorial is outdated. how do I enable authentication today, in mongoDB 4.4.25, mongosh 2.1.1?

Comment: It's not "how" that was wrong, it's "where" - see my update. RBAC was added in 2.4 a decade ago and didn't change much since then. As a side note 4.4 is on the last leg. It will reach "living impaired" state in few months.